# Execute Jquery in React Portals

Tags: jquery, reactjs, datatables, react-portal

I am developing a React application that uses React Portals. I have been able to load the portal in a new window with given data (portal represents the data in a table.). Now I want to add the Jquery DataTable library on that table in the Portal but I am unable to do so. I assume that my Jquery libraries and DataTable initiation function are not working in the Portal.

Note: I tried to add a simple onClick, but I couldn't be able to run it.

Please see the below code segments for your references.

***Load the Portal with "Restaurants" Component in my parent component***

```
<RankingWindowPortal>
    <Restaurants
        restaurants={this.props.restaurants}
        selected={this.state.selected}
        formValues={this.state.formTags}
    />
</RankingWindowPortal>
```

***RankingWindowPortal Component***

```
class RankingWindowPortal extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // STEP 1: create a container <div>
        this.containerEl = document.createElement('div');
        this.externalWindow = null;
    }

    copyStyles(sourceDoc, targetDoc) {
        Array.from(sourceDoc.styleSheets).forEach(styleSheet => {
            if (styleSheet.cssRules) { // for <style> elements
                const newStyleEl = sourceDoc.createElement('style');

                Array.from(styleSheet.cssRules).forEach(cssRule => {
                    // write the text of each rule into the body of the style element
                    newStyleEl.appendChild(sourceDoc.createTextNode(cssRule.cssText));
                });

                targetDoc.head.appendChild(newStyleEl);
            } else if (styleSheet.href) { // for <link> elements loading CSS from a URL
                const newLinkEl = sourceDoc.createElement('link');

                newLinkEl.rel = 'stylesheet';
                newLinkEl.href = styleSheet.href;
                targetDoc.head.appendChild(newLinkEl);
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        // STEP 2: append props.children to the container <div> that isn't mounted anywhere yet
        return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.containerEl);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // STEP 3: open a new browser window and store a reference to it
        // this.externalWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=1920,height=1080');
        this.externalWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=1700,height=900,left=300,bottom=300');
        this.copyStyles(document, this.externalWindow.document);

        // STEP 4: append the container <div> (that has props.children appended to it) to the body of the new window
        this.externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.containerEl);

    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // STEP 5: This will fire when this.state.showWindowPortal in the parent component becomes false
        // So we tidy up by closing the window
        this.externalWindow.close();
    }
}

export default RankingWindowPortal
```

***Restaurants Component***

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "../styles/restaurants.css"
import logo from "../resources/summit.png"
import RankingFooter from "./rankingfooter";
import $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery';

import "datatables.net-dt/js/dataTables.dataTables"
import "datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"

$( function() {
    $( "#sort-table" ).DataTable();
} );

export default class Restaurants extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="rankingPageHeader">
                    <div className="headerLogo">
                        <img src={logo} width="218" height="43"  alt=""/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="headerTitle">
                        
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div className="col-12 mx-auto">

                    <div className="card">
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <table className="table table-bordered sort-table table-condensed" id="sort-table">
                                <thead className="bg-success">
                                <tr>

                                    {this.props.formValues.map((formItem, index) => {
                                        return formItem.tag === 'glRank'  && formItem.value?
                                            <th className="text-center tableHeaderStyle">Rank</th> :
                                            formItem.tag === 'name'  && formItem.value?
                                                <th className="text-center tableHeaderStyle">Restaurant</th> :
                                                formItem.tag === 'slice'  && formItem.value?
                                                    <th className="text-center tableHeaderStyle">Goal</th>:
                                                    formItem.tag == 'hourDaily'  && formItem.value?
                                                        <th className="text-center tableHeaderStyle">Hour IP</th>:
                                                        formItem.tag == 'hourAv'  && formItem.value?
                                                            <th className="text-center tableHeaderStyle">Hour Avrg</th> :
                                                            formItem.tag == 'hourAch'  && formItem.value?
                                                                <th className="text-center tableHeaderStyle">Hour %</th> :
                                                                formItem.tag == 'hourCss'  && formItem.value?
                                                                    <th className="text-center tableHeaderStyle">Cars Hour - Today</th>:
                                                                    formItem.tag == 'dailyCss'  && formItem.value?
                                                                        <th className="text-center tableHeaderStyle">Day IP</th>:
                                                                        formItem.tag == 'dailyAv'  && formItem.value?
                                                                            <th className="text-center tableHeaderStyle">Day Avrg</th>:
                                                                            formItem.tag == 'highlight'  && formItem.value?
                                                                                <th className="text-center tableHeaderStyle">Day</th> :
                                                                                null

                                    })}
                                </tr>

                                </thead>
                                <tbody>{this.renderItems()}</tbody>

                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <RankingFooter/>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try appending your jQuery scripts to the window element you've created, that way they would be available in the portal's DOM.

For instance, you could do in your componentDidMount():

```
let s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "<your-js-paths>";
this.externalWindow.document.head.append(s);
```

In addition to that, you could add an event listener like

```
this.externalWindow.addEventListener('load', () => {
    // Code you'd like to run
});
```